# Android: Sax Reader, can't extract information needed

Tags: android, xml, equals, sax

I am receiving a response from a XML request and I need to deal with it. The response will return either '00' when the request has been accepted and the account is verified and a '03' when the account is invalid.

Currently the Sax Reader is returning the correct information but I cannot extract the information from the reader so I can store the username / password into the internal storage of the phone.

The code from the Sax Reader is:

```
public void inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                boolean errorCode = false;

                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
                {
                    System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ErrorCode")) 
                    {
                        errorCode = true;
                    }
                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,String qName) throws SAXException 
                {
                    System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);
                }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException 
                {
                    if (errorCode) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("ErrorCode : "+ new String(ch, start, length));
                        if (ch.equals(00))
                        {
                            System.out.println("IT WORKS!!!");
                        }
                        errorCode = false;
                    }
                }
            };
            saxParser.parse(is, handler);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Sax Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

As you can see in the public void characters it is printing out the errorcode that is relevant from the response. I am currently trying to do `ch.equals(00)` in a If statement but it isn't picking out the correct information! Could it be a problem that ch is a char data type?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I got it working. Instead of using '00' and '03' error codes. I have used the length of the response messages which are 'OK' and 'Invalid'. But out of interest, anyone still know how the fix the original problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Instead of using '00' and '03' error codes. I have used the length of the response messages which are 'OK' and 'Invalid'.